# Are Power Crystals a finite resource in Clank in Space?

Tags: clank, clank-in-space

Are Power Crystals a finite resource in Clank in Space? There are only 5 physical tokens included in the game. When these are in the hands of users, does that mean that no one else is able to obtain one (until one is somehow returned to the supply)?

Comment: Added [tag:clank] tag. There's precedent for including the base game tag in questions even for questions specific to an expansion.

Comment: not really an expansion, it's a stand alone re-implementation. Clank and Clank in Space have there own expansions that can not be combined with the other versions.

Comment: @Jungkook Re-implementations are also called "standalone expansions". And the distinction you bring up is irrelevant here. Take for example [tag:ticket-to-ride] and [tag:ticket-to-ride-europe]. The point is that someone following or searching for the base game is highly likely to be interested in the Q&A related to expansions too.

Comment: Ticket to ride is a bit different compared to clank. The non-standalone expansions of ticket to ride are compatible with ttr and ttre. The expansions for 'normal' clank can not be played with clank in space (or clank legacy) and visa versa.

Comment: @Jungkook Re "*Ticket to ride is a bit different compared to clank*", Not at all. Europe has its own board, its own cards and its own rule variations. This is exactly the same situation as Space.  //  Re "*The non-standalone expansions of ticket to ride are compatible with ttr and ttre*", Yes, so it makes no sense to bring them up. // These off-topic, incorrect, pointless  comments are becoming annoying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, power crystals are a limited component and there are also other ones that are limited in the game. A quick review of the rules states that the only unlimited component in the game is credits and in the list of limited components it calls out power crystals.

https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/4e/e4/76-clank-in-space-rulebook.pdf

> Limited Components — Most components in the game are limited and can
> run out if the players acquire enough of them. Most notably, this includes
> Power Crystals, Market items, and the cards in the Reserve (FAZR, Boldly Go,
> and Memory Core). The only unlimited components are the Credits. If you
> should run out of those, make any suitable substitution.

> Power Crystal — Some reward spaces on the board give you a Power Crystal.
> The Power Crystals are a limited component. Some of your cards may provide
> bonuses that work much like a faction bonus: if you have a Power Crystal, you
> may use those bonuses. You only get the bonus once, no matter how many
> Power Crystals you have.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

- There's a Major Secret that gives victory points for each Power Crystal one possesses. An unlimited supply of Power Crystals would provide a unlimited supply of points for the owner of that Secret. Anything that encourages a player to spend the entire game walking back and forth between two squares is a problem.
- There's a cards whose effect is multiplied by the number of Power Crystal one possesses. An unlimited supply of Power Crystals would provide a unlimited benefits from those cards. Anything that encourages a player to spend most of the game walking back and forth between two squares is a problem.
- There is precedent for limited quantities of resources, namely the items in the market.